# Possible mistake in book choosing Kth child

Tags: probability

Suppose that there exist N families on the earth and that the maximum number of children a family has is c. For $j=0,1,2 \ldots c$, let $\alpha_j$ be the fraction of families with $j$ children ($\sum_{j=0}^c\alpha_j=1$).

A child is selected at random from the set of all children in the world. Let this child be the $K$th born of his or her family; then $K$ is a random variable. Find $E(K)$.

**Textbook Solution:**

Let $A_j$ be the event that the person belongs to a family with j children. Then$$P(K=k)=\sum_{j=0}^cP(K=k|A_j)P(A_j)=\sum_{j=k}^c\frac{1}{j}\alpha_j$$

Therefore$$E(K)=\sum_{k=1}^ckP(K=k)=\sum_{k=1}^ck\sum_{j=k}^c\frac{1}{j}\alpha_j=\sum_{k=1}^c\sum_{j=k}^c\frac{k}{j}\alpha_j$$

I feel that there is a problem with $P(A_0)$. We can't condition on this event. Am I right? My solution is $$ P(K=k)=\frac{\sum_{i=k}^c\alpha_i}{\sum_{l=1}^cl\alpha_l}$$ and $$E(K)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^c\sum_{i=k}^ck\alpha_i}{\sum_{l=1}^cl\alpha_l}$$

Comment: Well, let's suppose that $c=1$ and that half the families have $1$ child and half have $0$ children.  Then we know that $K=1$ so $E[K]=1$.  The book's answer would be $\sum_{k=1}^1 \sum_{j=k}^1 \frac kj \frac 12=\frac 12$ which is wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz  The problem is that having chosen a child you know that the child was not born to a childless family.  Thus you have to rescale the $\alpha_i$ accordingly.

Comment: @lulu I think it's even worse than that. Clearly $P(A_j)\neq \alpha_j$ in general because that fails in the case $j=0.$ But just rescaling $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_c$ still doesn't give you $P(A_j).$ The problem is that by selecting a child at random from all children, you are biasing toward larger families. Consider the case $c=2,$ $\alpha_0=0,$ $\alpha_1=\alpha_2.$ There is a $\frac23$ probability the child is from a two-child family although there are equal numbers of one-child and two-child families.

Comment: @DavidK.  Yes, you are correct.  We need to specify the way in which the child was selected.  If the selection is uniform amongst all the children then you are certainly correct.  If you select a family (with children) uniformly and then a child uniformly from that family then rescaling works.  But I agree that the first interpretation is almost certainly what was intended.

Comment: Under the assumption that each child in the world has the same probability of being chosen, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $N\alpha_j$ families with $j$ children in the world described in the question, therefore
$S = \sum_{j=0}^c j(N\alpha_j) = N\sum_{j=0}^c j\alpha_j$ children altogether.
(Note that $S = N E(X)$ where $X$ is the number of children in a randomly chosen family.)

The most reasonable interpretation of randomly selecting one of these children is that each child has $\frac 1S$ probability to be selected, regardless of which family the child belongs to.

From that it follows that 
$$P(A_j) = \frac{j\alpha_j N}{S} = \frac{j\alpha_j}{\sum_{m=0}^c m\alpha_m}.$$
We could put this into the textbook answer instead of the incorrect
$P(A_j) \stackrel?= \alpha_j.$

But I think I like your approach better. There is one $k$th-born child in each family of $k$ or more children.
Hence the total number of $k$th-born children is
$N\sum_{j=k}^c \alpha_j,$
and therefore
$$ P(K = k) = \frac{N\sum_{j=k}^c \alpha_j}{S}
 = \frac{\sum_{j=k}^c j\alpha_j}{\sum_{m=0}^c m\alpha_m},$$
which is the formula you derived.
Therefore I agree with your solution.

---

Here is another approach. Consider the contribution each child makes to $E(K).$
Number all the children from $1$ to $S$ and let $k_i$ be the birth order of child number $i.$ Then
$$ E(K) = \frac1S \sum_{i=1}^S k_i.$$

Separate the sum into subtotals for each size of family.
For example, for $0 \leq m \leq c$ there are $N\alpha_m$ families of size $m$ and each of those families has one child with $k_i = 1,$ one child with $k_i = 2,$ and so forth up to their one child with $k_i = m.$
So the contribution of one family of size $m$ to the sum is $1 + 2 + \cdots + k.$
Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^S k_i
& = N\alpha_1 + N\alpha_2(1 + 2) + N\alpha_3(1 + 2 + 3) +
\cdots + N\alpha_m \sum_{k=1}^m k +
\cdots + N\alpha_c \sum_{k=1}^c k \\
& = N\alpha_1 + 3N\alpha_2 + 6N\alpha_3 +
\cdots + \frac12 m(m+1)N\alpha_m +
\cdots + \frac12 c(c+1)N\alpha_c \\
&= \frac12 N \sum_{m=1}^c  m(m+1)\alpha_m.
\end{align}

Therefore

$$ E(K) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^S k_i}{S}
 = \frac{\sum_{m=1}^c  m(m+1)\alpha_m}{2\sum_{j=0}^c j\alpha_j}.$$

I believe this is equal to your solution as well.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution too. I'm guessing there is no way to show those two are equivalent algebraically?

Comment: I have only worked it out in my head, not on paper (which is why I only say "I believe" they are equal), but I am fairly sure it **is** possible to algebraically manipulate one of the two answers into the other. You could try reversing the order of summation in your answer; note that since the inner summation's limits depend on the outer summation's variable, you have to change the limits of both summations when you reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

The fraction of families with $j$ children is not the same thing as the probability that a child chosen at random belongs to a family with $j$ children. You have used $\alpha_j$ to represent these two different quantities. For example, if half the families have $0$ children, the fraction of families with $j$ children is $1\over2$, but the probability that a child chosen at random belongs to a $0$-child family is $0$. As @lulu suggests, it is not the case that $P(A_j)=\alpha_j$. You have to do more work to figure out what $P(A_j)$ is. It is not just $\alpha_j$.